# How dangerous is to repair a stopcock without closing the main water entrance?

Tags: plumbing-fixture

I have, more or less, the situation bellow. I have simplified the scheme. It's a bathroom, (A) is a shower, (B) is a tap.
I would like to repair both A and B. The main stopcock doesn't work anymore.
Assuming I keep both A and B open while repairing one of them to alleviate the pressure, is it still too dangerous?

I'm trying to anticipate as much as possible problems that can occur before trying anything.

In another bathroom where the main stopcock works and have a similar layout, I was able to hold the water with the finger while simulating a repair. Not without lots of water in my chest.

[image: water column]

Comment: Do you have a water tank that is dedicated to this house alone?

Comment: It's a 4 floor apartment building. Its

Comment: What is the material of the piping: copper, galvanized steel, PVC, PEX?

Comment: PVC pipe. 20mm, 25mm

Comment: Wow, that's a serious problem when you don't have valves where you need to have valves.  Also if there is building management, **this is *their* problem** and they need to deal with it.  Usual disclaimers about not allowed to self-work on rental units etc.

Answer (score 1):

As far as danger there is 9 meters of head approx that will be close to 14 psi slightly less so as a pressure hazard it’s not a big deal but if you cannot replace the parts quickly the water may end up causing problems weather you keep the other valve flowing or not.  Knowing the size of the supply pipe and valves would help to provide more information.

Comment: A and B are 1/2''. The main is wider. I guess it's 3/4''. Going up in the building I don't know, maybe even wider. 1/2'' is more or less 20mm.

Comment: With the supply being at least 3/4 the difference in pressure won’t be much with 1 valve vs 2 valves. I would have all the parts handy and just swap them out as d.george mentioned dry ice can create a plug of ice I have done this also on water pressures up to 120 psi.

Comment: 120psi with or without ice?

Comment: @Ed Beal I thought freezing water in a copper or galvanized steel pipe would expand and damage the pipe? Or is it possible to do this for a short length of pipe without damage? What about damage to other piping materials?

Comment: I have done this many times with both galvanized and copper up to 120 psi with dry ice . Only freezing a short section so the ice is not trapped , this works especially well with low pressure as long as the ice can expand you only have a localized plug, put dry ice on more than 1 place a few inches apart and it can split between the points (oops in my youth I thought if 1 spot is good 2 is better it’s just the opposite) trying to get fittings back together with 40 psi can be tough but 15 psi on a small fitting  not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think you must ask the manager of the building to shut off the water at the tank long enough for you to change the shut off to your apartment. Then you can use your new shutoff valve to  change your internal valves.

Answer (score 0):

If this is your own home, I would call the municipal water company and ask about the possibility of shutting off the feed line to the house, and installing a new valve on that feed line. If they will shut the water off for a short time, even for a few minutes, you could buy a compression type valve or a shark bite valve and have them shut off the water long enough to cut the supply line and install a valve in that line. Another option would be to freeze the line with "dry ice" and make the repair. I have done this on copper feed lines up to 2". I would purchase shaved dry ice, put it into a towel, and carefully wrap the line with the dry ice in the towel,  and cover that dry ice towel with a second one for insulation. Use about an 6" or larger section of dry ice to freeze. Wait for the line to freeze and make the repair. When the repairs are completed remove the dry ice. If you choose this fix, please be careful and wear gloves and safety glasses for your safety. Remember dry ice is extremely cold.  The line will stay frozen until the dry ice is removed. There are also "Plumbers"  who can do this if this repair is above your skill level. Once you put in a main line shut off valve, replacing other valves and doing other repairs can be accomplished.

Comment: Dry ice would stop the flow but the utility stopping the flow? It is a water tank above.

Comment: Will ice work on PVC pipes?

Comment: Also, There is no visible pipes.